# Starting and Stopping Spring integration project

Tags: spring-integration

My SI project consists of managing data flowing between queues and interaction with database.  I don't want to use a servlet container to run the app.

In my development env am running main() to initialize the ApplicationContext.  How do I start the app as well as execute  controlled/graceful shutdown in 
controlled env like UAT/Production?

Need your valuable suggestion/pointers on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you register a JVM shutdown hook on the context, a `kill <pid>` will close the application context.

You can use JMX (or user code) to shut down the integration flow in an orderly fashion; see [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#jmx-shutdown).